# Angular 5 cannot make post request with retrived token

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular5

Hy i am having a problem making a post request in angular 5. The retrived token is correct, if i test it with postman i get the expected data. Can someone give me a hint, maybe i am using something wrong.

AuthService.ts

```
 getProfile(){
this.loadToken();
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/users/authenticate', {headers: headers}).map(res => res);
  };

  loadToken() {
    console.log(this.authToken);    //undefined here
    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    console.log(this.authToken)     // correct token here
  }
```

ProfileComponent.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      console.log('1', profile);
      this._router.navigate(['/profile'])
    }, err => {
      console.log(`Error`, err);      // IT GOES STRAIGHT HERE
      return false;
    });
  }

//ERROR OUTPUT
   HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/profile", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: The error states that the url you specified is wrong or does not exist

Comment: 404 means your api path is invalid

Comment: Also `HttpHeaders` set/append methods are immutable so you have to chain your append methods. `new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.authToken).append(...);`

Comment: I tried the retrived token with Postman and i got the data i wanted. Tanks for the chaining @LLai

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this :

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.authToken).append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

TANKS for chaining @LLai

Comment: I follow your answer, then I get Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http/api/website' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. Do you know how to solve this?